# IIS 7 Web App losing authentication when URL case is changed

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

We are experiencing odd behavior with our web application.  If I change the URL to uppercase, or parts of it, after authenticating with the app, I then have to re-authenticate.  Here's an example:

https://host.domain.com/website/asp

If I copy and paste that URL into a new tab after authenticating it will automatically authenticate and bring me to the landing page.  However if I paste this into a new tab, while another tab is already authenticated:

https://host.domain.com/webSITE/asp

I have to re-authenticate with the app.  (or IIS, this I'm not sure about)

This poses a problem when objects are developed without case being a consideration and I would think this behavior wouldn't be desirable.  I will be reaching out to the application vendor but I'm wondering if anyone has experienced such an issue with IIS 7.

Thanks,
Max

Comment: What authentication system are you using? Forms? HTTP Basic/Digest/Windows?

Comment: Windows Authentication with Kernel-mode enabled.

Answer (score 0):

IIS is generally case insensitive.  Where sensitivity comes into play is with integrating modules.  Modules like rewrite can be case sensitive.  You didn't specify, but is your IIS application using rewrite at all?  Also, your vendor may have controllers that are doing case sensitivity checks.  But my guess would be the actual browser to be the culprit.  Browsers that base cookies on the URL path can make those cookies case-sensitive.  See this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Geneva/thread/b5715cbe-6db0-4f59-a26e-f26d2c90ef26) for more information on users that have reported the same problem.